# Allow filenames with spaces in Joomla media manager

Tags: joomla3.0

Joomla media manager does not allow you to upload files with spaces in the filename providing the error message 'File name must only contain alphanumeric characters and no spaces'. Does anybody know if there is an option in Joomla or a way I can allow the upload of files with spaces in the name through the media manager?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing research on this right now. So far most sources I've seen seem to indicate that there is no such option. Even to the point of it being an issue posted on the bug tracker, to which the explanation given is that apparently file-names can't contain UTF-8 names which seems a little far fetch, but I don't know.

http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/%3Faction%3DTrackerItemBrowse&tracker_id%3D32/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=33161&start=8350

There is mention of a duplicate to which I would love to find, but it was not linked to this question so I don't know which duplicate is referred to.